# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when implementing Perceptron, see code below

Tags: python, iteration, perceptron, non-type

I have a problem with my perceptron codes.I receive this when I execute my code. I checked my two txt files and I am pretty sure the two of them are definitely ok. So can someone help? Thanks a lot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "perceptron.py", line 160, in <module>
    test()
  File "perceptron.py", line 133, in test
  w,k,i = p.perceptron_train('train.txt')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Data():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.len = len(x)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Perceptron():
    def __init__(self,N,X):
        self.w = np.array([])
        self.N = N
        self.X =X

    def prepare_training(self,file):
        file = open(file,'r').readlines()
        self.dic = set([])
        y = []             
        vocab = {}

        for i in range(len(file)):
            words = file[i].strip().split()
            y.append(int(words[0])*2-1)
            for w in set(words[1:]):
                if w in vocab:
                    vocab[w].add(i)
                   if i < self.N and len(vocab[w]) >= self.X:
                        self.dic.add(w)
                elif i < self.N:
                    vocab[w] = set([i])

        x = np.zeros((len(file),len(self.dic)))     
        self.dic = list(self.dic)
        for i in range(len(self.dic)):
            for j in vocab[self.dic[i]]:
                x[j][i] = 1
        self.training = Data(x[:self.N],y[:self.N])
        self.validation = Data(x[self.N:],y[self.N:])
        return x,y

    def update_weight(self,x,y):
        self.w = self.w + x * y

    def perceptron_train(self,data):
        x,y = self.prepare_training(data)
        self.w = np.zeros(len(self.dic),int)
        passes = 0
        total_passes = 100
        k = 0

        while passes < total_passes:
            print('passes:',passes)
            mistake = 0
            for i in range(self.N):
                check = y[i] * np.dot(self.w,x[i])
                if (check == 0 and (not 
np.array_equal(x[i],np.zeros(len(self.dic),int)))) or (check < 0):
                        self.update_weight(x[i],y[i])
                        mistake += 1
                        k += 1   
            passes += 1
            print('mistake:',mistake)
            if mistake == 0:
                print('converge at pass:',passes)
                print('total mistakes:', k)
                return self.w, k, passes

    def perceptron_error(self,w,data):
        error = 0
        for i in range(data.len):
            if data.y[i] * np.dot(w,data.x[i]) < 0:
                error += 1
        return error/data.len

    def test(self,report):
        x = np.zeros(len(self.dic),int)
        for i in range(len(self.dic)):
            if self.dic[i] in report:
                x[i] = 1
        if np.dot(self.w,x) > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def perceptron_test(self,data):
        test = open(data,'r').readlines()
        y = []
        mistake = 0
        for t in test:
            y0 = int(t.strip().split()[0])
            report = set(t.strip().split()[1:])
            r = self.test(report)
            y.append(r)
            if (y0 != r):
                mistake += 1
        return y,mistake/len(test)

    def predictive_words(self):
        w2d = {}
        for i in range(len(self.dic)):
            try:
                w2d[self.w[i]].append(self.dic[i] + " ")
            except:
                w2d[self.w[i]] = [self.dic[i] + " "]
        key = list(w2d.keys())
        key.sort()
        count = 0
        most_positive = ""
        most_negative = ""
        for i in range(len(key)):
            for j in range(len(w2d[key[i]])):
                most_negative += w2d[key[i]][j]
                count += 1
                if count == 5:
                    break
            if count == 5:
                break

        count = 0
        for i in range(len(key)):
            for j in range(len(w2d[key[len(key)-i-1]])):
                most_positive += w2d[key[len(key)-i-1]][j]
                count += 1
                if count == 5:
                    break
            if count == 5:
                break
        return most_positive,most_negative


def test():
    p = Perceptron(500,30)
    w,k,i = p.perceptron_train('train.txt')
    print(p.perceptron_error(w,p.validation))
    normal,abnormal = p.predictive_words()
    print('Normal:\n',normal)
    print('Abnormal:\n',abnormal)
    print(p.perceptron_test('test.txt'))

def plot_error():      
    x = [100,200,400,500]
    y = []
    for n in x:
        p = Perceptron(n,10)
        w,k,i = p.perceptron_train('train.txt')
        y.append(p.perceptron_error(w,p.validation))
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

def plot_converge():      
    x = [100,200,400,500]
    y = []
    for n in x:
        p = Perceptron(n,10)
        w,k,i = p.perceptron_train('train.txt')
        y.append(i)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

`perceptron_train` has the implicit return value `None` if `mistakes!=0`, so that's what you're seeing here.

Comment: the mistakes are always equal to 60. So how should i change my code? It should be 0

Comment: Also return something meaningful outside the while, or if that does not make sense, raise an Exception.

Comment: And ofc investigate why you do not get the convergence you expect in the amount of passes you do.